# Runtime error :java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table

Tags: java, file-transfer

i'm attempting to fetch a list of files from server and copy them to directory .
and this error prompts.

```
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table

at javafxhomeui_1.HomeUI_2Controller.writeFileToLocalHDD(HomeUI_2Controller.java:427)
at javafxhomeui_1.HomeUI_2Controller.initialize(HomeUI_2Controller.java:312)
```

HomeUI_2Controller.java

```
    RemoteInputStream ris= null;
    File[] iconlist=null;
    try {
        File appicon=new File("D:\\SERVER\\Server Content\\Apps\\icons");
        iconlist=appicon.listFiles();
        for (File file1 : iconlist) {
             ris = downloadcontroller.getFile(file1.getAbsolutePath());
             System.out.println(file1.getName());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HomeUI_2Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

try {
        for (File file1 : iconlist) {
            //System.out.println("D:\\client\\Temp\\"+file1.getName());

 /*line:312 */            writeFileToLocalHDD(ris,"D:\\client\\Temp\\"+file1.getName());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HomeUI_2Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

public static void writeFileToLocalHDD(RemoteInputStream inFile, String fileLocation) throws IOException {
    // wrap RemoteInputStream as InputStream (all compression issues are dealt
    // with in the wrapper code)
/* line:427*/ InputStream istream = RemoteInputStreamClient.wrap(inFile);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(istream);


    //downloaded file...
    File file = new File(fileLocation);



    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }


    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    FileChannel channel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();

    byte b[] = new byte[1024];
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (bis.available()>0) {
        bis.read(b);
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000);
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
        channel.write(buffer);
    }


    bis.close();
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    channel.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();


}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public RemoteInputStream getFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    // create a RemoteStreamServer (note the finally block which only releases
    // the RMI resources if the method fails before returning.)
    //read data
    RemoteInputStreamServer istream = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                fileInputStream);
        istream = new SimpleRemoteInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
        // export the final stream for returning to the client

        //send data
        RemoteInputStream result = istream.export();
        // after all the hard work, discard the local reference (we are passing
        // responsibility to the client)
        istream = null;
        return result;
    } finally {
        // we will only close the stream here if the server fails before
        // returning an exported stream
        if (istream != null) {
            istream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////

Comment: could you mark the line the exception points at? And show class signatures?

Comment: @Deltharis code updated

Comment: Are you using http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/rmiio/RemoteInputStreamServer.html and http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/rmiio/RemoteInputStreamClient.html ?

Comment: @Deltharis yeah i do

Answer (score 0):

rmi works on a stub and skeleton structure.
Exception that is thrown has something to do with rmi Registry. The Object is not found because it is not available from RMI resistry. 
*A NoSuchObjectException is thrown if an attempt is made to invoke a method on an object that no longer exists in the remote virtual machine*
as in [javaDoc of the Exception thrown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/NoSuchObjectException.html)